# How can I set this cron job?

Tags: cron

Which runs every 2 minutes between 9 am to 5:30 pm? I can make it run if its 9 to 5 but just not getting that 5:30 pm? Is there a way out?

PS: Except for splitting the jobs

Comment: What about making it two jobs?

Answer (score 9):

Just do two cronjobs.

```
*/2 5-16 * * * your_script
0-30/2 17 * * * your_script
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the cron job every two minutes, so just "*/2 * * * * *" in the cron entry.

Then have the actual script check if the time is >9:00 and <17:30